# I can't find the flaw - a diferentiable function which is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was solving a problem from a book and after quite some thinking I somehow drifted away and I was able to construct a function which is not continuous at the point $x=0$ but is differentiable at $x=0$. Of course this cannot be right but I can't find my mistake.

$f(x) = 3x+5$ for $x \le 0$

$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2} + 3x$ for $x>0$

The left and right derivatives are both equal to $3$ at the point $x=0$, right?

So how come?!

Comment: Left- and right-differentiable.

Comment: What is your *definition* of differentiable?  The definition I know implies that *if* the derivative at a point exists, *then* the left- and right-derivatives exist (and have the same value as the derivative). It does not imply that the converse holds.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Isn't the converse also true?

Comment: @peter.petrov No.  Absolutely not.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Do you have an example?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4794134/i-cant-find-the-flaw-a-diferentiable-function-which-is-not-continuous?noredirect=1#comment10193917_4794141

Comment: @XanderHenderson I'm not sure I follow this unless you have a different definition of left-derivative than simply, a one-sided limit of difference quotients.  As I understand it, problem with OP is that the right derivative doesn't exist -  if somehow it did exist and was equal to the left hand derivative then we would indeed have differentiability - but this would imply continuity as well.

Comment: @MW If I want to talk about the limit of the difference quotient from the left or right, I tend to phrase things in terms of left- or right-Dini derivatives, but I have seen elementary texts (not ones that I like, but they exist) which define left and right derivatives as limits of derivatives.  Which, again, is why I asked the original asker to *give definitions*.

Comment: @XanderHenderson fair enough if people have defined it that way (I've deleted my other comment).  I've never heard of defining derivative as a limit of derivatives but I'll take your wod for it.

Comment: @MW I mean, you could be right that the intended definition was a left- and right-limit of the difference quotient.  The original asker didn't give *any* definitions, so it is really hard to know.

Comment: @MW Exactly, thanks a lot.

Comment: @peter.petrov What makes you believe the right derivative exists? Please rather edit your post than answer by a comment.

Comment: The problem I think, is that you computed $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)$, rather than the right-detivative.

Comment: Not sure why my question got downvoted. Seems we had a pretty good discussion here. Thanks to everyone who commented or responded.

Comment: @peter.petrov It was likely downvoted for precisely the reason it was originally closed, i.e. you did not provide sufficient [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/).  For example, you did not provide the *basic definitions* (which I asked you to provide).

Comment: @XanderHenderson I see. Obviously you downvoted. I think you are just sour maybe because you were yourself confused not less than me. And yet you keep asking for definition(s) from me. Your whole intervention into this discussion was inadequate. Obviously the whole question was caused by me not being clear on some definition(s) (otherwise why would I bother to write it). When I saw the accepted answer, I checked Wikipedia and it took me just 2 mins to get my flaw. Yet you kept and still keep insisting about definitions. As I said... totally inadequate intervention from your side. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @peter.petrov Whether or not you believe me, I am not the downvoter.  And I have asked you to include definitions because *that is the way that things are done here*.  The goal of this site is to produce a repository for future readers, not just to provide tutoring to an individual.  I would also note that, as a general rule, when you are trying to do mathematics, you *must* start with the definitions.  If you had just written down the definitions (like I asked you to do), I would imagine that you would have found the error.  Isn't this better than being spoonfed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x) = 3$, but that's not the same as the right derivative. From the definition, the right derivative is

$$ f'_+(0) = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(0+h) - f(0)}{h} $$

if that limit exists. So

$$ f'_+(0) = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\frac{h^2}{2} +3h - 5}{h} $$

Do you see the problem now?

Comment: I think I see it, yes. Thank you. I will rethink all this again tomorrow. I guess the late hour contributed to my confusion.

Comment: While it is true that the left- and right-derivatives disagree, I don't think that this really addresses what I believe to be the underlying misconception in the question, i.e. that a function with equal left and right derivatives at a point is differentiable.  Take, for example, $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if $x\le 0$} \\ x+1 & \text{if $x >0$}\end{cases}$$  This function has equal left-and right-derivatives at zero, but is not differentiable at zero.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Hm, but according to the answer above the function you give has no right derivative defined because the difference quotient tends to plus infinity. So you are now adding to my confusion :)

Comment: It depends on what your definition of a right derivative is.  Which is why I asked you, below your question, to define your terms.

Comment: @XanderHenderson How many definitions do you know? I know just that one which is also in Wikipedia - see the one dimensional case. According to it what you are saying is incorrect. There no multiple definitions here, I think.

Comment: @XanderHenderson What you are looking at is the one sided limits of the derivative, not the one sided derivatives. That *is* a common error. In general, $f'_+(a)$ need not be equal to $\lim_{x\to a^+} f'(x)$. The OP, and your example, are computing the latter, not the former.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4794134/i-cant-find-the-flaw-a-diferentiable-function-which-is-not-continuous?noredirect=1#comment10193951_4794134